# JPA one-to-one with secondary table for root entity

Tags: jpa, outer-join, one-to-one

Following situation:

An root-Entity is build up from two database tables.

```
@Table("A")
@SecondaryTable(name="B", pkJoinColumns = {
                @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "key1", referencedColumnName = "key1"),
                @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "key2", referencedColumnName = "key2")})
```

The root entity contains an one-to-one association to an other entity lets call it "sub"

```
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumns({
          @JoinColumn(name = "key1", referencedColumnName = "key1", updatable = false, insertable = false),
          @JoinColumn(name = "KVSTU", referencedColumnName = "KVSTUFE", updatable = false, insertable = false),
          @JoinColumn(name = "CODE_TARF_GEN", referencedColumnName = "TARIFGENERATION", updatable = false,
              insertable = false)
  })
private Sub sub;
```

Every thing works fine, but the JPA provider (in my case EclipseLink) doen't create an (outer) join. Instead of a join, for every dependend sub-entity an extra query is created.

I also tried pk join columns instead of join columns for the one-to-one association, with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `@JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER)`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but the eclipseLink annotation is not avaliable in the project. We can only use the JEE / Jakarta standard annotations. The JPA implementation is hidden from the code.

Comment: Well, in such a case, you can try to write a custom query with `JOIN FETCH` to the related entity, but other than that, there's no portable way of forcing JPA to perform a join rather than a separate select